# Getting device location Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, location

I'm new to android but my current project requires to work with gps tracking. I've searched the web to find some answers, and some topics confused me. Can you tell me please, I'm not sure I've understand:

- Where do we need to use coarse and when fine?
- whats the main difference between using `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and `GPS_PROVIDER`?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies):

> If you are using both `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and `GPS_PROVIDER`, then you need to request only the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, because it includes permission for both providers. Permission for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` allows access only to `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

So in short, the difference is the level of details of the location you get.

The **network provider** determines the location of the users using cell towers, wifi access points etc. Distance between towers and user’s position are considered in the case of cell towers. This location provider offers a faster response but can be fuzzy.

The **GPS provider** determines the location of the users using satellites. This is usually more precise, but takes more time.

*Note*: there is also a `PASSIVE_PROVIDER`, which doesn't actively requests location, but is able to *eavesdrop* on other app's requests, i.e. it gets location information when other apps ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Fused Location Provider** gives the *location* technology and gives you the best location.This *api* gives the user access to the best location without using much power on the device.

Add to your **manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

In **activity** code

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient flpClient;
flpClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
```

to get the last known location

```
flpClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    // Logic to handle location object
                }
            }
        });
```

Look at the api for further explanation https://developer.android.com/training/location/